# How to say “I pass” in Chinese, when playing a board game

Tags: translation, word-choice

In many board games it is a valid move to pass, i.e. “not make a move at all”.

How do I express the intention to do this, in Mandarin Chinese, over text?

Neither of these direct translations seem to be correct:

I pass -> 我通过

I don’t want to do anything -> 我不想做任何事

Comment: "过、
要不起、
不要"
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1rz411i7aK?from=search&seid=994060400613151284

Answer (score 2):

When playing cards and want to skip a round, you can simply say "過", so the dealer will deal the card to the next person who wants it. You sit out one round of card dealing but remain in the game with the chance to win.

Comment: I remember a game where a group take turns counting upwards, and you say 过 when your number contains a digit 7, or if its divisible by 7.

Comment: "讓" (yield to the next) and "跳過" (jump/skip to the next) are in use as well but not as common as "过".

Answer (score 1):

In `斗地主(Fight The Landlord)` game, you can say `要不起` or `不要`. In other games, you can use `过` or `跳过`. When in a formal occasion, you may say `我弃权`.

Answer (score 0):

It's 弃权, (Qì Quán)

--- to abstain,

--- to forfeit one's right, privilege,

--- to waive one's right.

弃 --- to abandon;

权 --- a right, a power, an advantageous position.

Comment: Sometimes just saying 过 (equivalent to pass) is fine.

Comment: Yes, of course 过 is fine, in an informal sort of way, so long as the verbal indication is understood among the players. Actually there is no "official" way unless the Rules of the Game specifically designate strict verbal indications of intention in order to avoid confusion and even cheating. So there are words like "check", "Hold", even "Hit me", "I am out" used. If  过 is the commonly understood verbal indication among a group of players, then so be it. I do agree that 弃权 is a bit too formal or "stiff" in a game among friends, but it is not wrong or incorrect.